# Подключение к сторонней БД не заполненной в стандартном конфиге Laravel

Tags: база-данных, laravel

Используется laravel 5.8.0. Есть несколько баз данных, данные которых заполняются из админки. В стандартный конфиг (/config/database.php) данные, само собой, не попадают, а записываются и хранятся в отдельном JSON-конфиге (/storage/app/databases.json).

Вопрос следующий:
**Как можно подключиться к сторонней БД не при помощи занесения данных в конфиг вручную, а используя для подключения свои данные, получаемые автоматически?**

Знаю про существование `setConnection()`.
Попытался написать что-то такое:

```
$servers = conf()->get('servers'); //Пакет garf/laravel-conf, тут у меня массив с информацией по базам
foreach($servers as $server){
    if(empty(Config::get("database.connection.".$server['name_database']))){
        Config::set( // И через config() тоже работать не будет
            'database.connection.'.$server['name_database'],
            [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'host' => $server['ip_database'] ?? '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => $server['port_database'] ?? 3306,
                'database' => $server['name_database'],
                'username' => $server['user_database'],
                'password' => $server['pass_database'],
                'unix_socket' => '',
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'prefix_indexes' => true,
                'strict' => true,
                'engine' => null,
            ]
        );
    }
    $punishment = new Punishment;
    $punishment->setConnection($server['name_database']);
    $list = $punishment->where('name', '=', Auth::user()->name);
}
```

Но Laravel чёрт-с два захочет заносить что-то в свой конфиг программно, поэтому получаю ошибку:

> InvalidArgumentException
>   Database [server_classic] not configured.

P.S Просто напрямую писать подключение (через то же PDO) не вижу смысла. И про "используй одну базу" не писать, тут так не получится, потому что сторонние базы используются локально на игровых серверах и для серверов, а на сайт нужно получать только изредка некоторую информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте класс - наследник от `\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager` и переопределите в нем метод `configuration()`. Для примера я создал этот класс в `\App\Database\DatabaseManager`. В результате должно получится примерно так:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Database;

   use \Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager as BaseDatabaseManager;

   class DatabaseManager extends BaseDatabaseManager
   {
       protected function configuration($name)
       {
           // аргумент $name содержит название подключения

           // по названию подключения находим и возвращаем соответствующий конфиг
           $servers = conf()->get('servers');
           if (!empty($servers[$name])) {
               $server = $servers[$name];
               return [
                   'driver' => 'mysql',
                   'host' => $server['ip_database'] ?? '127.0.0.1',
                   'port' => $server['port_database'] ?? 3306,
                   'database' => $server['name_database'],
                   'username' => $server['user_database'],
                   'password' => $server['pass_database'],
                   'unix_socket' => '',
                   'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                   'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                   'prefix' => '',
                   'prefix_indexes' => true,
                   'strict' => true,
                   'engine' => null,
               ];
           }

           return parent::configuration($name);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Чтобы заменить стандартный DatabaseManager нашим измененным классом, создайте свой `DatabaseServiceProvider`:

   ```
   php artisan make:provider DatabaseServiceProvider
   ```

Laravel создаст его по пути `\App\Providers\DatabaseServiceProvider`. Измените его код следующим образом:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Database\DatabaseManager;
use Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider as BaseDatabaseServiceProvider;

class DatabaseServiceProvider extends BaseDatabaseServiceProvider
{
    protected function registerConnectionServices()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('db.factory', function ($app) {
            return new ConnectionFactory($app);
        });

        $this->app->singleton('db', function ($app) {
            // здесь создается объект нашего кастомизированного менеджера вместо стандартного
            return new DatabaseManager($app, $app['db.factory']);
        });

        $this->app->bind('db.connection', function ($app) {
            return $app['db']->connection();
        });
    }
}
```

3. В файле `config/app.php` в секции `providers` замените стандартный `DatabaseServiceProvider` на новый:

   ```
   //Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
   \App\Providers\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
   ```

**Как это должно работать**.

> В DatabaseManager::configuration() можно реализовать любую
>   логику получения конфигурации для соединения с БД. Этот метод на входе
>   получает название соединения, которое прописано (или указано динамически) в  свойстве $connection модели
>   или указывается явно через DB::connection(), а возвращает необходимый
>   массив параметров для подключения.

Применительно к вашей ситуации. Все настройки для подключений вы получаете таким образом:

```
$servers = conf()->get('servers');
```

`$servers` у вас должен иметь примерно такую структуру:

```
    $servers = [
        'connection_1' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'host_1',
            ...
            // остальные параметры подключения к первой БД
        ],
        'connection_2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'host_2',
            ...
            // остальные параметры подключения ко второй БД
        ],
    ];
```

Использовать одну модель на разных БД можно так:

```
$punishment = new Punishment();

$punishment->setConnection('connection_1');
dump($advert->count()); // будет выведено количество моделей в первой БД

$punishment->setConnection('connection_2');
dump($advert->count()); // будет выведено количество моделей во второй БД
```

Или то же самое через прямое обращение к таблицам:

```
// получение количества записей таблицы в первой БД
dump(\DB::connection('connection_1')->table('punishments')->count());

// получение количества записей таблицы во второй БД
dump(\DB::connection('connection_2')->table('punishments')->count());
```

Comment: > аргумент $name содержит то, что указано в $connection модели
А если модель всего одна нужна, и нужно перебором для каждой БД соединиться, взять данные и пройти дальше (как выше, например), а подключено БД может быть неопределённое количество (10-20 вполне себе)? Просто я так понимаю, для указанного в `$connection` определяется подключение к БД, и потом можно с вызовом подключаться к бд? Если так, то нужно как-тов модель тогда динамически передавать название соединения, это возможно?

Пока сделал так, как Вы указали, но по-прежнему выдаёт "... not configured".

Comment: дополнил ответ пояснением "Как это должно работать".

Comment: Понял, спасибо.